# Informix grouping based on static values returned in query

Tags: sql, informix

I have a query which currently works and it returns me a bunch of product numbers, I want to group these product numbers down to a product group level. These groups do NOT exist in the database.

I currently have the list like this:

```
'Metro 60'  '63782-1-4000','63782-1-5000','63778-1-4000','63778-1-5000','63780-1-5000','63776-1-4000','63776-1-5000','63772-1-4000','63772-1-5000','63774-1-4000','63774-1-5000','63784-1-5000','63786-1-5000'
'Elements WA'   '63782-1-4000','63782-1-5000','63778-1-4000','63778-1-5000','63780-1-5000','63776-1-4000','63776-1-5000','63772-1-4000','63772-1-5000','63774-1-4000','63774-1-5000','63784-1-5000','63786-1-5000','63774-2-1000','63782-2-1000','63778-2-0200','63772-2-1000','63776-2-1000','67744-1-5000','63770-2-1000','63768-2-0200','63772-5-1000','63774-5-1000','63774-5-3000','63760-2-1000','63748-5-4000','66757-5-1000','63774-5-2000','63494-1-5000','63486-1-5000','63476-1-5000','63486-1-6000','63495-1-5000','63487-1-5000','63487-1-6000'
'INDULGENCE'    '63782-1-4000','63782-1-5000','63778-1-4000','63778-1-5000','63780-1-5000','63776-1-4000','63776-1-5000','63772-1-4000','63772-1-5000','63774-1-4000','63774-1-5000','63784-1-5000','63786-1-5000','63774-2-1000','63782-2-1000','63778-2-0200','63772-2-1000','63776-2-1000','67744-1-5000','63770-2-1000','63768-2-0200','63772-5-1000','63774-5-1000','63774-5-3000','63760-2-1000','63748-5-4000','66757-5-1000','63774-5-2000','63494-1-5000','63486-1-5000','63476-1-5000','63486-1-6000','63495-1-5000','63487-1-5000','63487-1-6000','63530-1-5000','63536-1-5000','63534-1-5000','63532-1-4000','63532-1-5000','63528-1-5000','63531-1-5000','63537-1-5000','63535-1-5000','63533-1-5000','63529-1-5000'
```

etc

How can I group the results of my query to return this instead of the product.part_code?

Query:

```
Select  Product.part_code,
    sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty)) /1000 Sales_QTY,
    sum(salesstat.net_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) Gross_Revenue,
    sum(salesstat.net_prod_amt - salesstat.return_nprod_amt) Net_Revenue,
    Decode(sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty)), 0, Null,
        Sum(salesstat.net_prod_amt)/sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty))) *1000 Net_ASP,
    Decode(sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty)), 0, Null,
        sum(salesstat.cost_amt-salesstat.return_net_amt) / (sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty)) /1000)) Cost_Per_Thou,
    sum(salesstat.cost_amt-salesstat.return_cost_amt) Total_Cost,
    sum(salesstat.net_prod_amt - salesstat.return_nprod_amt)  - sum(salesstat.cost_amt-salesstat.return_cost_amt) Gross_Profit,
    Decode(sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty)), 0, Null,
        (sum(salesstat.net_prod_amt - salesstat.return_nprod_amt)  - sum(salesstat.cost_amt-salesstat.return_cost_amt)) / (sum(product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty)) /1000)) Profit_Per_Thou
from    Customer,
    salesstat,
    warereptdetl,
    Product,
    maingrp
Where   Product.part_code = salesstat.part_code
and product.part_code in ('63782-1-4000','63782-1-5000','63778-1-4000','63778-1-5000','63780-1-5000','63776-1-4000','63776-1-5000','63772-1-4000','63772-1-5000','63774-1-4000','63774-1-5000','63784-1-5000','63786-1-5000','63774-2-1000','63782-2-1000','63778-2-0200','63772-2-1000','63776-2-1000','67744-1-5000','63770-2-1000','63768-2-0200','63772-5-1000','63774-5-1000','63774-5-3000','63760-2-1000','63748-5-4000','66757-5-1000','63774-5-2000','63494-1-5000','63486-1-5000','63476-1-5000','63486-1-6000','63495-1-5000','63487-1-5000','63487-1-6000','63530-1-5000','63536-1-5000','63534-1-5000','63532-1-4000','63532-1-5000','63528-1-5000','63531-1-5000','63537-1-5000','63535-1-5000','63533-1-5000','63529-1-5000','63559-1-5000','63440-1-5000','63510-1-4000','63510-1-5000','63510-1-6000','63516-1-5000','63518-1-5000','63540-1-5000','63540-1-6000','63430-1-4000','63430-1-5000','63430-1-6000','63526-1-4000','63526-1-5000','63526-1-6000','63559-1-6000','63516-1-6000','63560-1-5000','63441-1-5000','63511-1-5000','63511-1-6000','63517-1-5000','63519-1-5000','63541-1-5000','63431-1-4000','63431-1-5000','63431-1-6000','63527-1-5000','63560-1-6000','63322-1-5003','63332-1-5003','63330-1-5003','63334-1-5003','63323-1-5003','63333-1-5003','63335-1-5003','63326-1-4000','63326-1-5000','63326-1-6000','63334-1-4000','63334-1-5000','63334-1-6000','63334-1-5004','63327-1-4000','63327-1-5000','63327-1-6000','63335-1-5000','63320-1-5000','63320-1-6000','63321-1-5000','63321-1-6000','63314-1-5000','63422-1-5000','63312-1-5000','63322-1-5000','63332-1-5000','63330-1-5000','63338-1-4000','63338-1-5000','63338-1-6000','63422-1-4000','63315-1-5000','63423-1-5000','63313-1-5000','63323-1-5000','63333-1-5000','63339-1-4000','63339-1-5000','63339-1-6000','63318-1-6000','63318-1-5000','63319-1-6000','63319-1-5000')
and customer.cust_code = salesstat.cust_code
and salesstat.rept_code = '0'
and warereptdetl.ware_code = salesstat.ware_code
and customer.cust_code in ('91826','22978','91247','48972','91386','91520','101472','98214','122586','108675','130703','120847','101155','96360','12005','34263','101517')
and salesstat.year_num = 2015
and salesstat.stat_type_code = 'MLY'
and salesstat.int_num = 9
and salesstat.ord_ind in ('7','8')
and maingrp.maingrp_code = salesstat.maingrp_code
group by Product.part_code
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I have now gotten this working and I have managed to pivot (Crosstab) the results but I would still like help if there is a better way to do this, surely I can use an "In" somewhere rather than a line per product?

```
Select  CASE trim(Product.part_code)
    WHEN '63782-1-4000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63782-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63778-1-4000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63778-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63780-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63776-1-4000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63776-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63772-1-4000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63772-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63774-1-4000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63774-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63784-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63786-1-5000' THEN 'Metro 60'
    WHEN '63774-2-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63782-2-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63778-2-0200' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63772-2-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63776-2-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '67744-1-5000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63770-2-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63768-2-0200' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63772-5-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63774-5-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63774-5-3000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63760-2-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63748-5-4000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '66757-5-1000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63774-5-2000' THEN 'Non-Standard pavers'
    WHEN '63494-1-5000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63486-1-5000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63476-1-5000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63486-1-6000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63495-1-5000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63487-1-5000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63487-1-6000' THEN 'Elements WA'
    WHEN '63530-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63536-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63534-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63532-1-4000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63532-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63528-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63531-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63537-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63535-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63533-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63529-1-5000' THEN 'INDULGENCE'
    WHEN '63559-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63440-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63510-1-4000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63510-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63510-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63516-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63518-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63540-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63540-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63430-1-4000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63430-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63430-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63526-1-4000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63526-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63526-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63559-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63516-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63560-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63441-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63511-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63511-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63517-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63519-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63541-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63431-1-4000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63431-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63431-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63527-1-5000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63560-1-6000' THEN 'Ocean Sands'
    WHEN '63322-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63332-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63330-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63334-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63323-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63333-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63335-1-5003' THEN 'Pioneer'
    WHEN '63326-1-4000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63326-1-5000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63326-1-6000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63334-1-4000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63334-1-5000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63334-1-6000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63334-1-5004' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63327-1-4000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63327-1-5000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63327-1-6000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63335-1-5000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63320-1-5000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63320-1-6000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63321-1-5000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63321-1-6000' THEN 'Symmetry'
    WHEN '63314-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63422-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63312-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63322-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63332-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63330-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63338-1-4000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63338-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63338-1-6000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63422-1-4000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63315-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63423-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63313-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63323-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63333-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63339-1-4000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63339-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63339-1-6000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63318-1-6000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63318-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63319-1-6000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    WHEN '63319-1-5000' THEN 'Western Earth'
    ELSE '0'
    END as ProdGrp,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 32 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre11,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 33 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre10,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 34 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre09,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 35 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre08,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 36 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre07,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 37 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre06,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 38 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre05,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 39 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre04,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 40 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre03,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 41 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre02,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 42 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Pre01,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 43 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week01,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 44 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week02,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 45 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week03,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 46 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week04,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 47 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week05,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 48 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week06,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 49 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week07,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 50 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week08,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 51 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week09,
    sum(CASE WHEN salesstat.int_num = 52 THEN product.cubic_qty*(salesstat.order_qty-salesstat.return_qty) /1000 ELSE null END) As Week10
from    Customer,
    salesstat,
    warereptdetl,
    Product,
    maingrp
Where   Product.part_code = salesstat.part_code
and product.part_code in ('63782-1-4000','63782-1-5000','63778-1-4000','63778-1-5000','63780-1-5000','63776-1-4000','63776-1-5000','63772-1-4000','63772-1-5000','63774-1-4000','63774-1-5000','63784-1-5000','63786-1-5000','63774-2-1000','63782-2-1000','63778-2-0200','63772-2-1000','63776-2-1000','67744-1-5000','63770-2-1000','63768-2-0200','63772-5-1000','63774-5-1000','63774-5-3000','63760-2-1000','63748-5-4000','66757-5-1000','63774-5-2000','63494-1-5000','63486-1-5000','63476-1-5000','63486-1-6000','63495-1-5000','63487-1-5000','63487-1-6000','63530-1-5000','63536-1-5000','63534-1-5000','63532-1-4000','63532-1-5000','63528-1-5000','63531-1-5000','63537-1-5000','63535-1-5000','63533-1-5000','63529-1-5000','63559-1-5000','63440-1-5000','63510-1-4000','63510-1-5000','63510-1-6000','63516-1-5000','63518-1-5000','63540-1-5000','63540-1-6000','63430-1-4000','63430-1-5000','63430-1-6000','63526-1-4000','63526-1-5000','63526-1-6000','63559-1-6000','63516-1-6000','63560-1-5000','63441-1-5000','63511-1-5000','63511-1-6000','63517-1-5000','63519-1-5000','63541-1-5000','63431-1-4000','63431-1-5000','63431-1-6000','63527-1-5000','63560-1-6000','63322-1-5003','63332-1-5003','63330-1-5003','63334-1-5003','63323-1-5003','63333-1-5003','63335-1-5003','63326-1-4000','63326-1-5000','63326-1-6000','63334-1-4000','63334-1-5000','63334-1-6000','63334-1-5004','63327-1-4000','63327-1-5000','63327-1-6000','63335-1-5000','63320-1-5000','63320-1-6000','63321-1-5000','63321-1-6000','63314-1-5000','63422-1-5000','63312-1-5000','63322-1-5000','63332-1-5000','63330-1-5000','63338-1-4000','63338-1-5000','63338-1-6000','63422-1-4000','63315-1-5000','63423-1-5000','63313-1-5000','63323-1-5000','63333-1-5000','63339-1-4000','63339-1-5000','63339-1-6000','63318-1-6000','63318-1-5000','63319-1-6000','63319-1-5000')
and customer.cust_code = salesstat.cust_code
and salesstat.rept_code = '0'
and warereptdetl.ware_code = salesstat.ware_code
and customer.cust_code in ('91826','22978','91247','48972','91386','91520','101472','98214','122586','108675','130703','120847','101155','96360','12005','34263','101517')
and salesstat.year_num = 2015
and salesstat.stat_type_code = 'WLY'
and salesstat.int_num > 31
and salesstat.ord_ind in ('7','8')
and maingrp.maingrp_code = salesstat.maingrp_code
group by ProdGrp
```

Comment: Make the definitions of the product groups exist in the database.  There's no sane alternative.  The CASE is ludicrous; use the database to store important information like the product groups.  Anyone would think you were using a spreadsheet or something.

Comment: For reasons out of my control I cannot write to this database in any way unfortunately (believe me I would LOVE to do it the way you have suggested). This is the only way I can come up with to get a legible report out of it that I can drop into a VBA ADO call and schedule to run on my VM each day I considered grouping in Excel but I figured the DB has more grunt than my VM so get that to do the legwork.

Comment: I suggest finding a new job, then.  If the rules are that stupid, it's probably time to go and find somewhere more amenable to work.  You can probably create a temporary table anyway — or several of them.  Do so.  Then run the report against the permanent and temporary tables, and when your session finishes, the temporaries will vanish.  The groupings should be in one temp table; the customer codes could be in another.  I have reservations about the pre/week column expressions, too.

Comment: Thanks, our system is a third party system which has many reliances hence the security, I was brought in to build a few automated reports in the interim then port to Salesforce Wave, we also have an ms sql db which will be used for the things wave can't do and will be my dev playground, for now I just need to get these temporary reports running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you want...

Anyway , here goes an option to work , considering you have only read grants.

- This example works with COLLECTION data type
- You cannot add/substract a value from a collection using standard SQL.
  So, you need inform all set of your products only once.

> ```
> create temp table tp01 ( prod char(10) , childs set( varchar(10) not null) ) with no log ; 
> insert into tp01 values ( 'p1' , set{"xyz", "abc", "ababa"});
> insert into tp01 values ( 'p3' , set{"aaa", "123", "999"});
>
> create temp table tp02 ( subprod char(10) ) with no log ; 
> insert into tp02 values ("xyz");
> insert into tp02 values ("abc");
> insert into tp02 values ("123");
> insert into tp02 values ("999");
> insert into tp02 values ("xxx");
> insert into tp02 values ("aba");
>
> select subprod
>      , tp01.prod
> from tp02 , outer tp01
> where tp02.subprod in tp01.childs
>
>
>
> subprod   prod
> xyz           p1        
> abc           p1        
> 123           p3        
> 999           p3        
> xxx           <null>
> aba           <null>
> ```

Comment: This is using the temporary table idea I suggested.  I probably wouldn't use the SET type, but it'll work OK.  There seems to be some resistance to the concept of even creating temporary tables, but AFAIK there's no way to stop someone creating temporary tables.  And they're automatically cleaned up at the end of a session, if they aren't explicitly dropped sooner, so there's no lasting change in the database.

Comment: Thanks ceinmart, this is what I was looking for. @JonathanLeffler there was no resistance to any potential solution that didn't involve modifying the database, I don't recall specifically refuting your idea of temp tables however there was no practical example given, a lot of what you said kind of got lost where you started telling me to find a new job!!!. Thank you both for your comments and assistance, I will apply the logic displayed above.